# Serial printf running GMP on STM32 with mbed framework

Tags: c, stm32, mbed

for a university project I'm working on a RSA-CRT implementation. I use *mini-gmp*, a subset of the GMP library for handling large integers.

Goal of the project is to run the program on a STM32F103 microcontroller, which I want to use with the ARM mbed framework.

Problem is I can't correctly print the large integers to the serial console for debugging. Here is a minimal working example of my code:

```
#include <mbed.h>
#include <mini-gmp.h>

//SETUP
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); // enable serial communication, tx, rx

int main(){

  pc.baud (115200);
  printf("STARTING\n\r");

  mpz_t n;
  mpz_init_set_ui(n,11242342351435632235235464577);

  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);
  printf("\nFINISHED\n\r");
}
```

When compiling with PlatformIO and running on the microcontroller I get this in the serial console:

```
STARTING
3485947265
FINISHED
```

I noticed the printed number always being 10 digits long and starting with a 3, the rest of the digits vary with the value of *n*. So it doesn't look like some kind of overflow to me.

Can someone here help me out?

Comment: That number takes more than 16 bytes to represent, perhaps you are running into a rollover issue because the register is not large enough?  The Windows Calculator won't let me enter the full number to see it's representation in hex.

Comment: Essentially you'd need 128 bits to store the number you are passing in, and your STM32F103 microcontroller is a 32 bit processor.  At best it will be able to work with 64 bit numbers.  You'll have to handle anything larger yourself.

Comment: I thought that's what GMP is for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype for `mpz_init_set_ui()` is

```
void mpz_init_set_ui (MP_INT *dest_integer, unsigned long int src_ulong);
```

It expects an `unsigned long` argument, which is 32 bits long on this platform. The C constant gets truncated to 32 bits **before** it's passed `to mpz_init_set_ui()`.

11242342351435632235235464577 mod (2^32) = 3485947265, that is whay you have got.

You should use a function that can initialize it with an arbitrary precision parameter, like `mpz_init_set_str()`.

Comment: Exactly this! Thank you very much!